# Jquery, JSONP Error 200, parseerror while message recieved

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

## 1) I'm trying to use a crossdomain api provided by netrunnerdb.com. The site requires a jsonp request or denies the request.

If you'd like more information on the api visit the website, there's a link for the api at the bottom of the page.

## 2) It's not my api that I'm calling

-- I have no control over the server, and I think the problem is that the json isn't being returned within the function that jquery sends as the callback.

## 3) My Ajax request:

```
var path="http://netrunnerdb.com/api/search/r<t d:c"
$.ajax({
    type:           "GET",
    url:            path,           
    cache:          true,
    dataType:       "jsonp",
    error:          function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(ajaxOptions);
        alert(thrownError);
    },
});
```

Here is the URL sent by the request:

```
http://netrunnerdb.com/api/search/r%3Ct%20d:c%20?callback=jQuery1110010968961869366467_1390750866847
```

## 4) The Response:

I get an error 200 thrown, I receive a parseerror, and then am informed that the json callback wasn't called. Is the response just malformed? Is there a workaround? In chrome if I copy the whole response by browsing directly to the above URL into the console and set a variable equal to it, it parses just fine into an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the response as JSON instead of JSONP, as the API doesn't recognise the callback from jQuery. The API expects the callback name in the `jsonp` parameter, not `callback`.

Add this to the properties in your Ajax call to make jQuery use `jsonp` instead of `callback` in the URL:

```
jsonp: 'jsonp',
```